# How to represent assign logic array in Verilog generate block?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have difficulties in representing a simple assignment with generate block.
My intention is 
      assign bus = disp[0] | disp[1] | disp[2] ...;
The following code does not work. How can I fix it? Such accumulation related assignments does not appear in the Verilog mannual.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
genvar varx;
for (varx = 0; varx < `N; varx = varx + 1) begin
    if (varx == 0) assign bus = disp[0];
    else assign bus = bus | disp[varx];
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an incorrect usage of generate and assign.

generates should not be used that liberally in Verilog and their use should be something special like extending a module for parametrization etc.

If it can be statically unrolled (as per your usage here) then a plain for loop could have been used. Generates would typically be used for parametrizing module instantiations;

`assign` should be once per wire and constantly drives the right hand side expression on to that wire.

Your code looks like you are simply trying to OR the `disp` bus, this can be achieved with an OR reduction operator:

```
wire bus;
assign bus = |disp ;
```

**Update1**

disp is actually defined as a memory and we are not trying to calculate a single bit or reduction. Here a for loop can be used to calculate the OR.

```
logic [3:0] data [5:0];
logic [3:0] or_data;
integer i;

always @* begin
  or_data = 4'b0; 
  for(i=0; i<6; i=i+1) begin
    or_data = or_data | data[i] ;
  end
end
```

Simple Simulation:

```
logic [3:0] data [5:0];
logic [3:0] or_data;
integer i;
initial begin
  for(i=0; i<6; i=i+1) begin
    data[i] = i*2;
  end
  #1ns;
  for(i=0; i<6; i=i+1) begin
    $displayb(data[i]);
  end

  or_data = 4'b0; 
  for(i=0; i<6; i=i+1) begin
    or_data = or_data | data[i] ;
  end
  #1ns;
  $displayb(or_data);
end
```